# MySQL flip table (pivot)

Tags: mysql, sql, pivot

** Update: thank you all guys! SUM did the trick. My query runs in less than 5 secs instead of my previous, lame solution which took 8 mins to give the same result!!**

I have a table which lists sales per product per day:

| day | product | quantity |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-09-19 | Apples | 15 |
| 2021-09-19 | Pears | 10 |
| 2021-09-19 | Potatoes | 5 |
| 2021-09-18 | Apples | 25 |
| 2021-09-18 | Bananas | 17 |
| 2021-09-17 | Potatoes | 3 |

I would like to see products and sales for the last days, given that today is "2019-09-19", like:

| product | c0 | c1 | c2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Apples | 15 | 25 | 0 |
| Pears | 10 | 0 | 0 |
| Potatoes | 5 | 0 | 3 |
| Bananas | 0 | 17 | 0 |

c0 is for today, c1 is for yesterday etc.

I think I have to use pivoting but I can't figure how ...
What I tried:

```
SELECT product,
COUNT(IF (DATE(day) = UTC_DATE(), quantity, 0)) AS c0,
COUNT(IF (DATE(day) = (UTC_DATE() - INTERVAL 1 DAY), quantity, 0)) AS c1,
COUNT(IF (DATE(day) = (UTC_DATE() - INTERVAL 2 DAY), quantity, 0)) AS c2
FROM sales
GROUP BY product;
```

But it gives the same count for every day ...
I need every product listed even if there were no sales on a day, ordered by the total sales DESC.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Use SUM() instead of COUNT().

Comment: If the answers helped you do not forget to upvote and select one of the answers as accepted so, others who might have your problem can pick one without hesitation and can learn from them

Answer (score 0):

You can dynamically pivot as desired through use of conditional sum aggregation along with window function namely `ROW_NUMBER()` such as

```
SET @sql = NULL;

SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(
             CONCAT(
                    'SUM(CASE WHEN day = "', day,'" THEN quantity ELSE 0 END) AS c',rn
                    )
       )
  INTO @sql
  FROM ( SELECT day, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY day DESC)-1 AS rn 
           FROM sales
          GROUP BY day  ) AS d;

SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT product,',@sql,' FROM sales GROUP BY product'); 
                  
PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=ad1da808024604b15e67229eb215ffa5)</kbd>

Comment: super thanks for the fiddle, very informative!

Answer (score 0):

You should use `SUM`:

```
SELECT product,
SUM(IF (DATE(day) = UTC_DATE(), quantity, 0)) AS c0,
SUM(IF (DATE(day) = (UTC_DATE() - INTERVAL 1 DAY), quantity, 0)) AS c1,
SUM(IF (DATE(day) = (UTC_DATE() - INTERVAL 2 DAY), quantity, 0)) AS c2
FROM sales
GROUP BY product;
```

Demo: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/7yUJcuMJPncBBnrExKbzYz/33

> COUNT(expr) [over_clause]   Returns a count of the number of non-NULL
> values of expr in the rows  retrieved by a SELECT statement.    If
> there are no matching rows, COUNT() returns 0.
>
> https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/aggregate-functions.html#function_count
>
> SUM([DISTINCT] expr) [over_clause]
>
> Returns the sum of expr. If the return set has no rows, SUM() returns
> NULL. The DISTINCT keyword can be used to sum only the distinct values
> of expr.
>
> If there are no matching rows, SUM() returns NULL.
>
> https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/aggregate-functions.html#function_sum